# How to validate column before importing into database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

I am a complete newbie to SSIS.

I have a c#/sql server background.

I would like to know whether it is possible to validate data before it goes into a database. I am grabbing text from a `|`(pipe) delimited text file.

For example, if a certain datapoint is `null`, then change it to `0` or if a certain datapoint's length is `0`, then change to `"nada"`.

I don't know if this is even possible with SSIS,  but it would be most helpful if you can point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

anything is possible with SSIS!

after your flat file data source, use a Derived Column Transformation. Deriving a new column with the expression being something like the following.

*ISNULL(ColumnName) ? "nada" : ColumnName*

Then use this new column in your data source destination.

Hope it helps.

Comment: using the "Script Task" from your toolbox. If you want to script for each row of a collection use a "Foreach ADO Enumerator" and pass the values as variables to the "Script Task". You can then access the variable in your main method using "Dts.Variables["variableName"].Value".

Comment: FYI - my origional answer above is not c# code it is SSIS expression syntax. please refer to this link for further information. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140206.aspx

Comment: thanks so much do you think ssis is the right solution for my problem?

Comment: its all kinda relative. SSIS is the recognised DTS solution but I have also scripted tasks like this, as @mikurski suggested below for quick wins. I think SSIS is more appropriate for reocurring tasks, or tasks managed within a project. if as you say your new to ssis perhaps this is the perfect introduction to it as its a relatively straight forward task? otherwise i would probably be better to advise scripting using this link as an aid. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191503.aspx. Basically pull all content from the file into a temp table and validate the content.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're dead set on using SSIS, but the basic method I've generally used to import textfile data into a database generally takes two stages:

1. Use `BULK INSERT` to load the file into a temporary staging table on the database server; each of the columns in this staging table are something reasonably tolerant of the data they contain, like a `varchar(max)`.
2. Write up validation routines to update the data in the temporary table and double-check to make sure that it's well-formed according to your needs, then convert the columns into their final formats and push the rows into the destination table.

I like this method mostly because `BULK INSERT` can be a bit cryptic about the errors it spits out; with a temporary staging table, it's a lot easier to look through your dataset and fix errors on the fly as opposed to rooting through a text file.